# How to run JavaScript in Firefox URL bar?

Tags: firefox, javascript

I am using Firefox and am trying to run this code on the URL bar `javascript:alert(document.cookie);`.

But, when I hit go, nothing happens. In Chromium, it alerts, so what is with Firefox? Does Firefox try HTTP by default? If so, then how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Firefox 89 and later

1. Select *Settings* menu (3 horizontal lines **≡** icon in the upper right corner) *More Tools* -> *Web Developer Tools* -> *Console* tab.
2. Type JavaScript code after the web console prompt `»` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The web console prompt will be located in the bottom left corner of
the console pane if the console already has output in it.

#### Firefox 72 and later

Scratchpad is deprecated as of Firefox 70 (bug 1565380), and has been removed in Firefox 72 and later.

1. Select *Settings* menu (3 horizontal lines **≡** icon in the upper right corner) -> *Web Developer* -> *Web Console*.
2. Type JavaScript code after the web console prompt `»` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Firefox 57-71

1. Select *Settings* menu (3 horizontal lines **≡** icon in the upper right corner) -> *Web Developer* -> *Scratchpad*.
2. Click the **Run** button on the Scratchpad toolbar to run your JavaScript code.

---

#### Firefox 56 and earlier

1. Open a new tab in Firefox and in the URL bar, and enter `about:blank` to display a blank tab so that you can see what you are doing.
2. From the Firefox menu select *Tools* -> *Web Developer* -> *Web Console*.
3. A new **Web Console** window will open. From the Web Console window click the **JS** button on the toolbar.
4. From the **Web Console** window click on the Scratchpad icon in the toolbar. The Scratchpad icon looks like a notepad.
5. A new **Scratchpad** window will open. Copy your javascript code: `javascript:alert('Hello, World')` in the Scratchpad window.
6. Click the **Run** button on the Scratchpad toolbar to run your JavaScript code.

Comment: [Scratchpad is deprecated as of Firefox 70 (bug 1565380), and will be removed as of Firefox 72 (bug 1519103).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Deprecated_tools#Scratchpad)

Answer (score 6):

For firefox android version, you can try this bookmarklet:

`javascript:var a=prompt();var f=Function(a);f();`

It will open a prompt box. Type your command in it (without "javascript:") and it will run.

Comment: I'm on desktop Linux, but this worked for me: `javascript:var a=function(){ alert(prompt()); }()`.  (Edit - added 'alert' around 'prompt' to show use of the output.)

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:` does not appear to be working anymore since the last update (FF 71.0  *Windows*).
There is no output in the *console* either.

Note that [Firefox 63](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/10/24/firefox-63-blocks-javascript-in-address-bar-by-default/) and above removes "javascript:" automatically when pasting into the address bar.

This can be changes in the settings page `about:config` by setting the key `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript`to false.

However, while it does not filter the `javascript:` when pasting into the address bar any more, it does not execute it.

"Bookmarklets" remain working.

I have not found any information on this change or bug yet:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=javascript
- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/71.0/releasenotes/

---

Mozilla calls the URL/address bar "unified search/address bar" / "the unified Awesome Bar" / "Firefox's URL bar":

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/get-started-firefox-overview-main-features#w_search-everything-with-the-unified-searchaddress-bar